# attributedString using attribute "firstLineHeadIndent" doesn't show correctly within a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to show an attributedString within a UILabel and I added "firstLineHeadIndent" property to its attributes.

With 16 characters of "国", it should break into two lines. But UILabel just show me 14 characters in only one line as shown in picture "not correct with 16 characters".

And it can show correctly when using 17 characters.Can anyone tell me why??
Here is my code:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 300, 80)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [self.view addSubview: label];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paraStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 40;
    paraStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    NSDictionary *attrs = @{
                            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paraStyle,
                            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightBold],
                            NSKernAttributeName:@.9f
                            };
    label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国" attributes:attrs];}
```

Not correct with 16 characters:

[image: not correct with 16 characters]

Show correctly with 17 characters:

[image: show correctly with 17 characters]

Comment: u solved ur problem

Answer (score 0):

[image]**Updated Answer**

change this line : to

```
   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 300, 80)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [self.view addSubview: label];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paraStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 20;
    paraStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    NSDictionary *attrs = @{
                            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paraStyle,
                            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16 weight:UIFontWeightBold],
                            NSKernAttributeName:@.9f
                            };
    label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国" attributes:attrs];
```

**solution 2 :**

*remove paragraph :*  thing

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 300, 80)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;

 label.text=@"国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国国";
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview: label];
```

Comment: still u r facing issue comment below..  @X.Tristan

Comment: UILabel has no change after adding these two sentences.. minimumFontSize is deprecated in iOS6.0.   And adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth doesn't work either.

Comment: if u set      **paraStyle.firstLineHeadIndent =15;**. it will show centre of ur label

Comment: check my new solution2     u can put any length data with respect of length it will fit@X.Tristan

Comment: I want to know why it doesn't show correctly with indent=40. Change value of headIndent can only fix this problem and the wrong display will still appear within other situations.

Comment: IF U SET 40 the starting position of the text will start from 40

Comment: seems UILabel break sentences into lines only when it's width is larger than frame, ignore of indent. When sentence's width plus indent is larger than frame, UILabel WON'T break the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, which I think is a bug of `UILabel`. So I try to change it to `UITextView`, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `NSTextAttachment` with a transparent image to add extra space.